# push viewController is not working while debugging in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Sometimes, **navigationController?.pushViewController** method is not working while debugging. My initial controller (self) has already navigation controller. However, we could not see any error log in output screen. Have you ever encountered this problem ? Is might be a memory problem ?

```
 let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as! MyViewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Environment: iOS 12, Xcode 10.1

Regards,

Comment: Depends on where you're doing this. Is your self.navigationController nil in the cases it doesn't work?

Comment: Where did you run this code ?. Can you share us

Comment: Add NavigationController before your initial ViewController. It's gonna work.

Comment: try moving you code inside if of `if let nav = self.navigationController {} else {//put some log}` and see getting any log while you getting problem. Since you are using option check `?` on `self.navigationController`, the push won't happen when `self.navigationController` is nil and no error or exception will be thrown.

Comment: did you add navigation controller before your first controller as a initial controller?

Comment: @MRizwan33 Its not neccessary. Above code should work. Its not relevant initial controller

Comment: Hi, my initial controller has already navigation controller.

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik then you are not getting my point. Okay. just check by using if let navigation to get nav controller you will get empty or somthing.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This suggestion would be valid if the call is being made from a thread that is not the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please make sure you have set navigation Controller as initial View controller

[image]

2. Then you can use this piece of code for moving between controllers

   ```
   let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as! MyViewController
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
   ```
3. To get back to the controller using Navigation use

   ```
   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```
4. And I Hope it is not a memory Problem.